# How can I make python import a module as soon as it is Invoked in terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, interpreter

I hate working in a clogged screen so as soon as I start working in the terminal I define a function as follow:

```
from os import system

cls = lambda: system('cls')
```

This way I can clear my window with the simple command `cls()`.

Is there a way that I can make python import that function as soon as I invoke the interpreter with the command `python`. Similarly as to how `__builtins__` gets imported.

This question is not just pertained to wanting to do this because I'm lazy to type 2 extra lines at every invoke, I also want to know a way that I can make python automatically import any module of my own making and where I should store that script.

Comment: You could using ipython

Comment: Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: create a  PYTHONSTARTUP file

Comment: you could also [add the startup code to `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/site.html#readline-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you need to set the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable in something like Security-System-advanced-environment variables:

Firts create a file `pythonstartup.py` with your code inside:

```
from os import system

cls = lambda: system('cls')
```

Then in your environment variables set `PYTHONSTARTUP="C:\path_to\pythonstartup.py"`

Comment: should I throw `pythonstartup.py` in `/pythonX.X/lib`?

Comment: Don't think it matters once you supply the path but I don't use windows so cannot say for sure, might be worth adding a print statement to make sure it is being imported.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I don't have that environment variable and creating it doesn't work either.

Comment: what does `path` show, can you see pythonstartup.py? You were not meant to have it you have to create it.

Comment: my `path` variable has value : `....C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\lib\pythonstartup.py`

Comment: put a `print("in startup file")` in `pythonstartup.py` and see if you see that printed when you start a shell

Comment: No nothing gets printed

Comment: ok then it is not finding the file, do you see PYTHONPATH listed under system variables?

Comment: Got it working thanks. I just needed to restart my laptop for some reason.